# Usage de "au royaume des aveugles, les borgnes sont rois"

Tags: usage, grec, proverbes

Ce [proverbe](http://www.linternaute.fr/proverbe/377/au-royaume-des-aveugles-les-borgnes-sont-rois/#:%7E:text=Au%20royaume%20des%20aveugles%2C%20les%20borgnes%20sont%20rois.%22&text=Entour%C3%A9%20de%20personnes%20ignorantes%20ou,intelligence%20passe%20pour%20un%20g%C3%A9nie.&text=Ce%20proverbe%20provient%20de%20la,par%20%C3%89rasme.) provient de la Grèce antique, et il est cité en français dès le XVIème s. par Érasme. Il signifie :

> Un médiocre paraît remarquable parmi des gens sans valeur ;
> il est facile pour un ignorant de briller parmi de plus ignorants que lui ;
> entouré de personnes ignorantes ou stupides, un individu doté d'un maigre savoir ou d'une maigre intelligence passe pour un génie ; etc.

Peut-on l'utiliser couramment ou son emploi est considéré non politiquement correct ?

> P.ex. : Dans une classe tous les élèves hormis un ont obtenu une note
> inférieure à 11 en maths. La meilleure note est 12 sur 20. Peut-on
> dire pour cet élève que "*au royaume des aveugles, le borgne est roi*"
> ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

J’ai déjà entendu plusieurs fois cette expression et elle est pour moi toujours couramment utilisée, en tout cas comprise.

En revanche, elle est effectivement politiquement peu correcte. Pour cela, je ne la vois être utilisée que dans certains cas : car (1) elle dénote toujours un certain sarcasme et (2) relève plutôt d’un style littéraire.

Donc une manière de l’utiliser serait dans cet esprit :

> Dans une classe tous les élèves hormis un ont obtenu une note inférieure à 11 en maths. La meilleure note est 12 sur 20. X, qui a eu la meilleure note, est très heureux, même si sa note reste passable. Mais comme le proverbe le dit, **au royaume des aveugles, le borgne est roi**.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand there is also the old saying

> Leur savoir n’estoit que besterie et leur sapience n’estoit que moufles ([Rabelais](http://agora.qc.ca/documents/Francois_Rabelais--Leducation_selon_Rabelais_par_Gabriel_Compayre#:%7E:text=Car%20leur%20savoir%20n%27estoit,meilleur%20langagee%20que%20votre%20fils.))

conveys also the same meaning.

> Leur savoir n'était que bêterie (bêtise) et leur sagesse n'était que moufle.

Voir https://www.france-pittoresque.com/spip.php?article5169